# Determine the iteration times using Pollard's rho Method for factoring

Tags: random-number-generator, factoring

Let's say, we have a large number $n=181937053$ and $f(x)=x^2+1$. And also we know that $n=12391 \times 14683$.

The problem is that ,using Pollard rho method, can we find the algorithm iteration times need to factor this number? ($x_0,y_0 = 2$)

Comment: I think you're supposed to implement the algorithm, then run it with code that counts the number of iterations until it succeeds. I don't think you'll be able to predict the number of iterations without running it.

Comment: Brock is correct; you can give a plausibility argument that it should usually take around $O(\sqrt{p})$ iterations (where $p$ is the smaller prime factor), but it looks unlikely you'll be able to say something like "this will take precisely 165 iterations" without actually running it.

Comment: If you could calculate the number of iterations $n$, faster than executing the algorithm, then you've discovered an algorithm more efficient than Pollard's Rho algorithm. It's not hard to find the value of the $n$th iteration of Pollard's rho algorithm in $\log(n)$ time, using square-and-multiply.